# Need to click element twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen most of the posts about this issue but none seems to work for me. (I am new to React)
Basically I have this js function:

```js
export function toggle() {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // Configure tooltips for collapsed side navigation
    $('.navbar-sidenav [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        template: '<div class="tooltip navbar-sidenav-tooltip" role="tooltip" style="pointer-events: 
        none;
        "><div class="
        arrow "></div><div class="
        tooltip - inner "></div></div>'
    })
    // Toggle the side navigation
    $("#sidenavToggler").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("body").toggleClass("sidenav-toggled");
            $(".navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse").addClass("collapsed");
            $(".navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level, .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third- 
                level ").removeClass("
                show ");
            });

        // Force the toggled class to be removed when a collapsible nav link is clicked
        $(".navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("body").removeClass("sidenav-toggled");
        });
        // Prevent the content wrapper from scrolling when the fixed side navigation hovered over
        $('body.fixed-nav .navbar-sidenav, body.fixed-nav .sidenav-toggler, body.fixed-nav .navbar- 
            collapse ').on('
            mousewheel DOMMouseScroll ', function (e) {
            var e0 = e.originalEvent,
                delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail; this.scrollTop += (delta < 0 ? 1 : -1) * 30; e.preventDefault();
        });
})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

which is used to make a sidebar smaller. The point is that I need to click twice to make the sidebar smaller. I am doing it like this. Here I receive the function:

```
const Border = ({ isClicked }) => (
```

And then calling it from the element:

```html
<a onClick="{isClicked}" className="nav-link text-center" id="sidenavToggler">
  <i className="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
</a>
```

This is the class that calls the const:

```js
class CitasPage extends React.Component {
  handleToggleCreate = () => {
    toggle();
    this.setState({});
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <Border isClicked={this.handleToggleCreate}></Border>
        <Citas />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CitasPage;
```

Comment: if you just to call twise, then call the function 2 times
is this handleToggleCreate() is working for you?

Comment: The problem is that to make the sidebar smaller I need to click it twice, but I want it to be smaller by clicking only once.

Comment: if you can create your problem in https://codesandbox.io/ i can solve it for you then

Comment: format question well and also include more code but maybe what you need is to count the number of times its click with a delta to include wait time for second click

Comment: use an conditional statement to check when its clicked once and no subsequent click comes in after 3 secs

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/htschmed/pen/EEGJZY (the sidebar toggler)